# Product of Diels-Alder reaction + Consecutive Reaction with base and heat

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

there is a problem regarding a Diels-Alder reaction that I do not understand (see image).
[image]

The Diels-Alder reaction of the diene and the dienophile should lead to the product A. I hope I did it correctly, because the molecular formular shall be C9H6O2N2.

Now, the base triethylamine is added and heat is applied. Because it is a very strong base I would deprotonate the proton next to the ester-group -COOR, since it has a -M effect. I think applying heat leads to decarboxylation (B = carbon dioxide). But I don't know what the product C looks like, since there is another reaction to product D.

Can you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: The pKa of the protons alpha to the nitriles is very similar to that of the proton alpha to the ester.

Comment: So if I take the proton alpha to the nitrile, then the negative charge can be stabilized by the nitrile. Can I then make a new double bond in the ring, so that a carboxylate forms? The carboxylate can then form carbon dioxide... So in the end another double bond in the ring forms and a CN- leaves. But does that even make sense?

Comment: Why does CN- leave if CO2 leaves? I think you will get a dicyanocyclohexadiene (C) which will spontaneously aromatise to give 1,2 dicyanobenzene

Comment: I am sorry, I still do not completely understand it. If CO2 leaves, then there is still a negative charge in the molecule. So what happens so that dicyanocyclohexadiene is formed?

Comment: There is also Et3NH+ present which can quench the anion. The diene will spontaneously lose H2 as the driving force for aromatisation is very powerful

Comment: @Waylander: Would you consider loss of HCN via Et3N in the last step to give benzonitrile.? Unfortunately, there is not sufficient information in the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is a possible pathway.

Comment: You have nothing to drive aromatisation without elimination, so HCN elimination is more likely in this case unless a weird ene reaction is occurring. Loss of H2  requires a catalyst in the majority of cases, which is not indicated here